# Question regarding look up search

Tags: lookup, administration, lookup-filter

There is one field, which is look-up to Opportunity. Now lets say there are 5 Opportunity records with name Anil.

- When I put "A" in that search, it shows 2 records,
- when I put "An", it shows 3 Anil records and
- when I put "Anil", it shows 5 records.

Why is it happening like this? What is happening behind this look-up search?

Answer (score 0):

As you start typing in a lookup field, the results adjust dynamically with records that have matches in the Name field.  Records includes recent items, items from your most frequently used objects and items from the current object. To find the correct record enter the full search term to display right matches.

You will see a list of auto-suggested results when you search in lookup field and these instant results are matches for the search term to the name field of the record. Again these results are dynamically displayed. However, if you perform a full search the returned results match the search term to all searchable fields for the object.

Check more details on lookup search of [classic](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_lookupdialog.htm&type=5) and [lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_lookup_lex.htm&type=5).

Also, see [limitation](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdl0jUAB/all-show-all-records-in-lookup-search) to display all records in lookup search, you can try [workaround](https://www.mandsconsulting.com/display-all-records-in-a-lookup-search-in-salesforce/) if you to still want to display all records on opportunity in lookup search.

Thanks